# How can I convert a string number to a number in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to convert this string:

```
my $string = "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine";
to 
my $string = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
```

Is there anyway to do this in Perl Regex for only one pattern?

Comment: So only single digits? No "fiftynine" ?

Comment: `s/zero/0/g; s/one/1/g; s/two/2/g;`

Comment: Yes, I want only single digits:D